# Jquery Click-handler doesn't work with named function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I feel like this is one of those problems you only run into after too little sleep or too many coffees...

I have an element

```
<a id="blah" href="#">somethinghere.com</a>
```

I define a function

```
function test(){
    alert('hi');
};
```

I try to attach the function as a click-handler(https://jsfiddle.net/8r1rcfuw/30/):

```
$('#blah').on('click', test());
```

and load the page, and the handler executes immediately - without any clicks.

However when I just use an anonymous function as a handler(https://jsfiddle.net/8r1rcfuw/36/) :

```
$('#blah').on('click', function(){
    alert('hi');
});
```

it works fine

Doing both (https://jsfiddle.net/8r1rcfuw/39/):

```
$('#blah').on('click', function(){
    test();
});


function test(){
    alert('hi');
}
```

seems to work fine - but seems a little redundant.

This feels like something I've done 1000 times before - what gives?

Comment: `$('#blah').on('click', test());` ==> `$('#blah').on('click', test);` Remove invocation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The event handler has to be a function, and you are passing the result of a function to it:

```
$('#blah').on('click', test());
```

is the same as:

```
$('#blah').on('click', undefined); //As your funcion doesn't return anything
```

Think of it as a function is a value, you can do:

```
var myFunction = function() {
    alert("Hi");
}
```

or

```
function myFunction() {
    alert("hi");
}
```

And then:

```
$('#blah').on('click', myFunction); //Without invocation!
```

or using an anonymous function:

```
$('#blah').on('click', function() {
    alert("Hi");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use  object of function :

```
var temp=function test() {
  alert('hi');
}
$('#blah').on('click', temp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
$('#blah').on('click', test); // your function name only
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ranvir/8r1rcfuw/42/)